# How to bind DataSet coming from .NET web service to android GridView?

Tags: .net, android, web-services, dataset, android-gridview

I'm calling a .net webservice which returns dataset, so how can i read dataset from service and bind it to android GridView?

I'm getting web service response like:

```
SoapObject obj=(SoapObject)response.getResponse();
```

here in "obj" 'm getting DataSet from .NET web service, so please tell me how can i read dataset into android GridView?

Thanks,
nag.

Comment: Any one provide me sample to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use DataSet types which are specific to the .NET framework.
Web Services best practices involve the usage of Plain Old Class Object (POCO)
You can read more on http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx

To quick fix it, you could map your dataset into a flat structure, but i sincerely advice you to stop exposing .NET dataset to other worlds

Comment: Ok then can i send by collection of objects? could you please provide me any samples of returning different types from service if you have.

Comment: You can do a method like : public List<Customer> GetCustomers(...) { ... } returning an array of Customer instances

Comment: I also have this same issue bt i am getting json object of dataset from webservices developed in c#.So please tell me how to bind data of dataset in android gridview..please help